# How can I generate Q-classes with QueryDsl 4.1.4 and Spring-Data-Jpa 2.0.0.M1?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, generated-code

I would like to update my version of Querydsl. I was looking for generating Q-Classes with the apt-maven-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
             <goals>
                  <goal>process</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                  <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
              </configuration>
          </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Some versions I 'm using:

```
<spring.security.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<spring.context.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.context.version>
<springdata.jpa.version>2.0.0.M1</springdata.jpa.version>
<springdata.es.version>2.0.5.RELEASE</springdata.es.version>
<springdata.common.version>2.0.0.M1</springdata.common.version>
<querydsl.version>4.1.4</querydsl.version>
```

But unfortunalty this generates me nothing on the generated-sources folder as expected. So can you give me some ways to understand what has failed in my Querydsl configuration please?

Thanks per advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My entities are stored in jar dependency. What about yours? Used to work with 4.0.7

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the `querydsl-apt` library is available on the build classpath.

> **Option 1**: Add the library as a dependency to the APT plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
      <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

> **Option 2**: Add the library as a project dependency

```
<project>
  ..
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
      <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Note `<scope>provided</scope>` in this case, which will ensure that the library does not get bundled with the application.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but I had also tried this solution and it didn't work for me. Any other significant idea guys? Thanks per advance.

Comment: Can you post your problematic project somewhere? Sample classes will do. I have a sample on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41386005) in case you would like to take a look and compare it with your project.