# Querydsl generation of qclasses

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

what's wrong with the following configuration?

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-query-dsl-classes</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jpa-export</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <targetFolder>target/generated-sources/query_dsl/qclasses</targetFolder>
                            <packages>
                                <package>com.test.data.jpa.domain</package>
                            </packages>
                            <sourceFolder>target/generated-sources/query_dsl/qclasses</sourceFolder>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The problem is that QClasses neither get generated or compiled when the project is compiled, as the QClasses are referenced in code, compilation cannot proceed, What is the correct configuration?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386005/how-can-i-generate-q-classes-with-querydsl-4-1-4-and-spring-data-jpa-2-0-0-m1/41390874#41390874).

Comment: It's not a duplicate: Sadath uses `com.querydsl` instead of `com.mysema.maven`. Like Sadath, I couldn't get this querydsl plugin working either.